# Let $G$ an commutative group of order $2n$ where $n$ is odd prime. Suppose $G$ has an element of order $n$. Show that $G$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

> **Let $G$ an commutative group of order $2n$ where $n$ is odd prime. Suppose $G$ has an element of order $n$. Show that $G$ is cyclic.**

I know that every group of even order has an element of order $2$. I don't know whether it is required or not.

**One can apply the the concept of upto the chapter Cyclic group** and First counting principle, $o(HK) = o(H)o(K)/o(HK)$.

Since, up to this problem, the book that I am following did not introduce Lagrange's theorem, Cauchy's Theorem for Abelian Groups, Sylow's Theorem for Abelian Groups, Cayley's Theorem, Quotient group, Normal Subgroup, Isomorphism etc.

Please help me to solve the problem **using the elementary tools** under the above restriction.

Comment: This is false as stated. Is $n$ an odd prime, perhaps?

Comment: @AlexWertheim Yes, Sorry for the typos. I am editing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will need to use the fact that $G$ has an element of order $2$. Let $x \in G$ have order $2$, and $y \in G$ have order $n$. Here is a hint. Using the fact that $G$ is abelian and the fact that $\gcd(2, n) = 1$, show that the order of $xy$ is $2n$, whence $G$ must be cyclic.

Here is a proof that any group of even order must have an element of order $2$. Let $|G| = 2n$, and let $\Omega = \{x \in G \mid x \neq x^{-1}\} \subseteq G$, i.e. $\Omega$ is the set of all elements of $G$ which do not have order $1$ or $2$. Note that if $x \in \Omega$, then $x^{-1} \in \Omega$, and $x \neq x^{-1}$ by the hypothesis that $x \in \Omega$. Hence, $\Omega$ has even order, so $G \setminus \Omega$ has even order. Since $e \in G \setminus \Omega$, $G \setminus \Omega$ has at least order $2$, whence $G$ must have an element of order $2$.

Comment: @AlexWerthein Thanks. But would you please give me a proof for the Hints that you have provided. I am not getting this well.

Comment: @user1942348: sure. Note $(xy)^{k} = x^{k}y^{k}$, since $G$ is abelian. We know that if $x^{k} = e$, then $2 \mid k$. We also know that if $y^{k} = e$, then $n \mid k$. Since $\gcd(2, n) = 1$, it follows that $2n \mid k$.

Comment: @AlexWerthein I understand that as $G$ is abelian then $(xy)^{k} = x^{k}y^{k}$. But how this is used in the solution? Your remaining part of answer above uses only: as $o(x)=2$ if $x^k=e$ then $2|k$. Also $o(y)=n$ if $y^k=e$ then $n|k$. Then $2n|k$ since $gcd(2,n)=1$.

Comment: That part is crucially used in the solution. Otherwise, we can't relate the order of $xy$ to the orders of $x$ and $y$. Do you see?

Comment: @AlexWerthein Thank you. I understand it. Is it possible to solve using the elementary tools and without using the fact that "every group of even order has an element of order 2" **directly**?

Comment: @user1942348: I'm not aware of any other way than the one I've posted. I don't think my proof uses any facts which are not elementary, though. If you need an elementary proof that every group of even order has an element of order 2 (i.e., one which does not appeal to Cauchy's theorem), I can post one.

Comment: I understand the proof. Yes, you have used elementary tools to solve. Thank you very much. I shall be happy if you post an elementary proof that every group of even order has an element of order 2. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1942348: No problem. I've updated my answer with a short proof - feel free to ask for more clarifying remarks. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have one more confusion.

Let $x,y\in G$ st $o(x)=2, o(y)=n$. Since $x,y\in G$ then $xy\in G$. Let $o(xy)=k$, then $$(xy)^k=e ~~~~(1)$$ but as $G$ is abelian $(xy)^k=x^ky^k$. By (1), $$(xy)^k=x^ky^k=e$$

Now you took if $x^k=e$ and $y^k=e$ then $ 2|k$ and $n|k$ (as $o(x)=2, o(y)=n$). As $gcd(2,n)=1$ then $2n|k$. Therefore $o(xy)=2n$ (as $k|2n$ also).

My query is, how you take $x^k=e$ and $y^k=e$? $(xy)^k=x^ky^k=e$ does not imply $x^k=e$ and $y^k=e$. If the definition of $k$ is different than I have assumed, please clear my doubts that occurs due to not understanding the definition of $k$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29808/discussion-between-user1942348-and-alex-wertheim).

Answer (score 2):

$G$ has an element of order $n$, say $g$. Also, since $|G|=2n$, $G$ has an element of order $2$ (by Sylow Theorem), say $h$. Since $G$ is commutative,
$$\langle g\rangle\langle h\rangle =\langle g\rangle \times \langle h\rangle.$$
Furthermore, this group has exactly $2n$ elements, so it is equal to $G$. Therefore $G$ is cyclic.